# Error: window.opener's property undefined

Tags: javascript, html

One page open another page(eg. openerdemo.html) using the window.open() method, but the popup page cannot access any property of the opener page.

Opener page code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="html/text"; charset="utf-8"  >
    <title>windowdemo</title>

    <script language="JavaScript">

        function openWin(thisurl) {
            popWin = window.open(thisurl, 'popupPage', "width=480,height=272");  
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="open" onClick="openWin('openerdemo.htm')"/>
</body>
```

Popup page(openerdemo.htm) code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="html/text"; charset="utf-8"  >
    <title>windowdemo</title>

    <script language="JavaScript">

        function closeWin() {
            window.opener.close();
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1><a href="#" onClick="closeWin()">close all</a></h1>
</body>
```

I use javascript console in Chrome, enter 'window.opener' to the cmd line of popup window, it's return:

> window.opener
>   'Window {}',

That means the opener window is not null, but its all property missing. However, if one page opens a new page like this:

popWin = window.open('', 'popupPage', "width=480,height=272");
  popWin.document.write("this is popupPage");

The popup page's window.opener is ref to the opener window, and just can control the opener window with the 'window.opener' object.
ex:

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100')
myWindow.document.write("This is 'myWindow'")
myWindow.focus()
myWindow.opener.document.write("This is the parent window")
</script>

</body>
```

I test this code in FF, IE and chrome.

Can anyone tell me how to control the opener window in popup page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would work fine, but you're making a cross-domain request. If the window you are opening and the window you opened it from are on the same domain, you wouldn't have a problem

Note: This may be classified as a cross-domain request when you are not using a webserver, but just using the file system (file:/// is your protocol). I haven't tested it - rest assured, however, that when you get it on the web, all will be well as long as both the opener and the openee are server from the same domain.

**EDIT**

I just did a quick test on my local file system and this is indeed the case - it's classified as a cross-domain request and is forbidden for security purposes - again, it won't be a problem when you put it on a webserver and serve both pages from the same domain.